# Why are cross-origin Image requests blocked by Cytoscape.js but not by d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, cytoscape.js

Although Cytoscape.js supports background images in nodes, I cannot display images which don't have the CORS (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing) header. Chrome throws the following error.

```
Access to image at 'https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/goldendoodle-dog-breed-pictures/puppy-4_1.jpg'
from origin 'https://null.jsbin.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is the image I'm trying to access - [image]

However, if I try to display the same image as background in a node using d3.js, the image gets displayed.

**Cytoscape.js**

```js
var cy;
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
      .selector('node')
      .css({
        'height': 60,
        'width': 60,
        'background-fit': 'cover',
        'border-color': '#000',
        'border-width': 1,
        'label': 'data(label)'
      })
      .selector('edge')
      .css({
        'width': 2,
        'line-color': '#ffaaaa',
        'target-arrow-color': '#ffaaaa',
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
      })
      .selector('#puppy')
      .css({
        'background-image': 'https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/goldendoodle-dog-breed-pictures/puppy-4_1.jpg'
      })
      .selector('#cat')
      .css({
        'background-image': 'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1261/1413379559_412a540d29_b.jpg'
      }),

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: 'cat',
            label: 'Images are supported'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'puppy',
            label: 'Desired image not being shown'
          }
        },
      ],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          source: 'cat',
          target: 'puppy',
          label: 'puppy'
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      name: 'circle'
    }
  }); // cy init


});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100;
  top: 100;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2018 by maxkfranz (http://jsbin.com/teworah/3/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <title>Images</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="cy"></div>

</body>
```

**d3.js**

```js
var config = {
  "avatar_size": 100
}

var body = d3.select("body");

var svg = body.append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');

data = [{
  posx: 100,
  posy: 100,
  img: "https://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/goldendoodle-dog-breed-pictures/puppy-4_1.jpg",
}];


svg.append('clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'clipObj')
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', config.avatar_size)
  .attr('cy', config.avatar_size)
  .attr('r', config.avatar_size);

data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  svg.append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', d.img)
    .attr('width', config.avatar_size)
    .attr('height', config.avatar_size)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + parseInt(d.posx + config.avatar_size / 2) + ',' + parseInt(d.posy + config.avatar_size / 2) + ')')
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clipObj)');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.16/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific example, if you set the `crossOrigin` to `anonymous` it does not work, but if you don't set it (i.e it is `null`), then it works.

By default Cytoscape.js sets the `crossOrigin` field of images to `anonymous` [see the doc](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image). There is no way of setting it to `null`.

But if you still want, you can play with the source code: setting the `crossOrigin` field to `null` [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/40a1a8f1e9e9e086ff8f4e43fb122194a2252b1f/src/extensions/renderer/base/images.js#L27) will display this specific image.

In this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4L7tnsdb/2/), if you set the origin to `null` it works, but setting it to `anonymous` does not work.

P.S: if you want, you can also run your snippets and analyze the response and request headers in the Network tab of Developer tools. In Firefox, you can edit the header, resend the request, and see how it affects the response.

Comment: Hey, I'm struggling with the very same issue. Setting 'null' where you say doesn't resolve it sadly :( Even in your JSFiddle, if we change 'null' to 'anonymous' it still works. Is there some navigator changes since 2019 ?

Comment: 2023, any workarounds?

Comment: i found a way, set `"background-image-crossorigin":"null"` in node css works, although it's "null" string and not the JS null